# What is the correct (functional) way to alter a list and return what was removed?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to learn scala, and decided to create a poker app to get my head around some of the class objects. I've got decks working fine, but I've got to the point where I need to draw 5 cards. So far I have:

```
import util.Random

case class Card(value: Int, color: String)

class Deck {
  private var deck = newDeck 

  def draw(amount: Int): List[Card] = {
    val ret = deck.take(amount)
    deck = deck.drop(amount)
    ret
  }

  def newDeck: List[Card] = {
    Random.shuffle((1 to 13).map(x => 
      List(Card(x, "D"), Card(x, "C"), Card(x, "H"), Card(x, "S"))).toList.flatten)
  }

  override def toString: String =  "Deck has " + deck.length + " cards left."
}
```

This draw function doesn't seem quite right having two steps - but I'm not sure how I else I can (or should) take the top however many cards, and leave the list in a state without those cards in?

(As an aside, if someone has a better function for the deck creation/shuffle I'm all ears, this seems a bit hacky too... but my main question is the list state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should rewrite the codes either:

**(a)** with **totally** immutable struct, i.e. **NO var**, **NO mutable collection**

**OR**

**(b)** replace `var deck: List[Card]` by some mutable collection, like `ListBuffer`.

Here is the **(a)** solution:

```
import util.Random

case class Card(value: Int, color: String)

class Deck(private val cards: Seq[Card]) {
  def draw(amount: Int): (Deck, Seq[Card]) = {
    val (ret, rem) = cards.splitAt(amount)
    (new Deck(rem), ret)
  }

  override def toString: String = "Deck has " + cards.size + " cards left."
}

object Deck {
  def apply(cards: Seq[Card] = Nil): Deck = cards match {
    case Nil =>
        val ncds = for(v <- 1 to 13; c <- Seq("D", "C", "H", "S")) yield Card(v, c)
        new Deck(Random.shuffle(ncds))
    case _ => new Deck(cards)
  }
}
```

Use case:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
//paste code here

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import util.Random
defined class Card
defined class Deck
defined object Deck

scala> val d1 = Deck()
d1: Deck = Deck has 52 cards left.

scala> val (d2, cards) = d1.draw(4)
d2: Deck = Deck has 48 cards left.
cards: Seq[Card] = Vector(Card(3,H), Card(2,S), Card(11,H), Card(8,C))
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside whether you want to have the deck be a "var", you can do that `take` and `drop` simultaneously, using `splitAt`

```
def draw(amount: Int): List[Card] = {
  val (ret, remainder) = deck.splitAt(amount)
  deck = remainder
  ret
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it have to be a var, since I'll be reassigning the value it contains?

I like the use of splitAt(), but the reassigning still seems a little messier than the examples I've seen so far. Having ret afterwards just seems like I'm arbitrarily avoiding using the return keyword, which I'm assured is A Bad Thing(tm)

Comment: Since it's a relatively simple example, it's great opportunity to ask: how would it look like if `deck` was a `val`? Whole class would be immutable, which means that `draw` would have to return e.g. `(List[Card], Deck)`, which seems more trouble than it's worth as opposed to a little, hidden mutable state...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek, you'd probably return a CardState object with lists of cards in the deck and in the hands, and the operation would be DrawCardsForPlayer (s:CardState, p;Player):CardState, or something. After all, you're going to do something with those drawn cars. In other words, the total number of cards doesn't change, just where they're currently located.

Answer (score 2):

The most purely functional way to solve this has already been written for you! Its `splitAt`, which models drawing as taking some amount of cards and returning the new state of the deck along with it.

This technique is used by [Queue.dequeue](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Queue) from the collections api:

```
def dequeue: (A, Queue[A])
//Returns a tuple with the first element in the queue,
//and a new queue with this element removed.
```

so `draw` would then be just:

```
def draw[A](amount: Int): (A, Queue[A]) = deck.splitAt(amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor note: You can avoid the `.flatten` if you use `.flatMap` instead of `.map` in the `newDeck` method. I don't know why you consider that method "hacky", it looks perfectly reasonable to me. Here is a variant using for-syntax:

```
def newDeck: List[Card] = {
  val sorted = for {
    value <- 1 to 13
    color <- Seq("D", "C", "H", "S")
  } yield Card(value, color)

  Random.shuffle(sorted).toList
}
```

Comment: Thats more like what I was looking for. I meant hacky in that it wasn't really manageable if there were more than four suits (not for cards obviously, but in general use).